# Moving to another server database connection error

Tags: database, errors, installation

I have some issues when I try to move it on other server.
This are the steps:

1. I go into my actual database through phpmyadmin, export the database.
2. I copy the entire folder of my wordpress website from FTP, and paste it through FTP on my new host.
3. I modify the wp-config.php with my new database details.
4. Now I enter on my new host phpmyadmin I import the database that was created from my old host.

   And now when I enter on my website, I receive: **Error establishing a database connection**
   I really need some help with this.
   Thanks!

Comment: Are you updating the site URL in the options table on the new db server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Error establishing a database connection** means a bad password, DB user, DB name or server location (usually localhost) in wp-config.php. Simple as that. Check and check again.

[Editing wp-config.php « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php)